# Upload/Publish Azure Webjob through FTP

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-webjobs

I have several Webjobs running through Azure. Most of the times when I make changes I only want to change 1-2 dll files.

Can I use FTP to upload those dlls and not go through the normal upload process through the portal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out you can. More details here: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/74215124623/deploy-azure-webjobs/